# {thmtools} changing a numbering by {amsmath}

Tags: amsmath, thmtools

Why would the simply loading of the package `thmtools` alter the numbering system predefined by `amsmath`? Just uncommenting the line on `thmtools` changes the numbering sequence on the document.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{thmtools}

% Theorem environments
    \newtheorem{myteo}{Theorem}
    \newtheorem{mylem}[myteo]{Lemma}

\numberwithin{myteo}{section}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{First Section}

\begin{mylem}
        Example of Lemma.
\end{mylem}

\begin{myteo}
        Example of Theorem.
\end{myteo}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`amsmath` does nothing related to theorems.

What happens is that you have `\numberwithin` in the wrong place, when `thmtools` is loaded.

And you don't need `\numberwithin`, actually.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools}

% Theorem environments
\newtheorem{myteo}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{mylem}[myteo]{Lemma}


\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{First Section}

\begin{mylem}
        Example of Lemma.
\end{mylem}

\begin{myteo}
        Example of Theorem.
\end{myteo}

\end{document}
```

[image]